# Kafka Streams - java version dependency

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am running my application with Java 1.6, and planning to integrate few aspect with Kafka.

I am exploring whether I should go for Kafka Consumer (using poll()) or use KafkaStreams APIs. Do we need Java 1.7 / 1.8 to work with Stream APIs ?

Comment: The Java version should not driver your decision, but you should rather upgrade your very very old Java version (not just for Kafka, but also for security reasons etc). The question if you want to use consumer or streams API depends on what you want to do...

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Consumer and Kafka Streams API, both have their own benefits.  Both can be used to read data from Kafka topics.   It depends very much on the use case you are trying to implement.

Kafka Consumer is a low level consumer client, where you can write your consumer application to read kafka topics and and implements the functionality.
While Kafka Streams is more expressive. It supports programming style DSL with operations where you can read data from the kafka topics, perform the operations and write back to another kafka topics.

Well, Kafka Stream API is built on top of Kafka consumer and producer client.  There are some noticable features of Streams API which you should consider:

1. Provide fault tolerant stateless and stateful transformations i.e. map, join, windowing and aggregation. While in kafka consumer client, implementing these operations are tedious.
2. Streams API provides functional programming style DSL with lots of operations which are straight forward to use. Also for the complex processing, there is low level processor API which can be used with DSL.
3. Streams API also supports interactive queries to expose the results as a microservice. While in Kafka consumer, you will have to write implementation for that.
4. Streams API can read from Kafka topics, do the processing and write back to another kafka topic. While consumer will read data and then you will have to write another Producer client to publish the data to topics.

Regarding the Java version, it is recommended to use Java 1.8 as old versions had some security vulnerabilities. But you can still run with Java1.7 version.

Comment: If you think, it answers your question, feel free to upvote/accept.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Kafka officially supports Java 1.6, or at-least the last couple of versions don't. [This](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html) page shows the JDK compatibility with different Kafka releases and the min version required is JDK 1.7

Comment: Do not see any dependency as per Apache Kafka Docs https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix, what you mentioned is for Confluent Platform.

Comment: Confluent Platform ships with Apache Kafka internally and thus has the same dependencies. Java 6 was dropped in 0.9 release (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2316); Java 7 in 2.0 release (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4423).

Comment: @Anil You can see there's a table which maps a confluent release to a vanilla Kafka release.